# How to deploy AKS without exposing cluster API to the internet?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, github-actions

How to deploy Azure AKS kubernetes in a private network mode without exposing cluster API to the internet?
I need to deploy React with Github actions and test that it's working

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

> In a private cluster, the control plane or API server has internal IP
> addresses that are defined in the RFC1918 - Address Allocation for
> Private Internet document. By using a private cluster, you can ensure
> network traffic between your API server and your node pools remains on
> the private network only.
>
> The control plane or API server is in an Azure Kubernetes Service
> (AKS)-managed Azure resource group. Your cluster or node pool is in
> your resource group. The server and the cluster or node pool can
> communicate with each other through the Azure Private Link service in
> the API server virtual network and a private endpoint that's exposed
> on the subnet of your AKS cluster.
>
> When you provision a private AKS cluster, AKS by default creates a
> private FQDN with a private DNS zone and an additional public FQDN
> with a corresponding A record in Azure public DNS. The agent nodes
> continue to use the A record in the private DNS zone to resolve the
> private IP address of the private endpoint for communication to the
> API server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/private-clusters?tabs=azure-portal